# How can I earn more gold?

Tags: rock-of-ages

Pretty straight forward, but in Rock of Ages, what are the best methods for earning gold?

In Single Player, the computer opponent seemingly has much more gold to build units with. This may be by design, but what things can I do to earn more gold to build more units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't many things to do to earn gold.

But a few are:

1. Flood the map with mines!
   Basically, build the highest... well, quality mine every round. You might think this is a stupid tip, but you will notice the difference when you actually do it.
2. Smash everything!
   When you are making your way to the enemy tower, smash the buildings. These are a very effective way to make gold, provided you don't waste half an hour doing it.